# Changing type on WSI file will not allow for an override

Tags: overrides, wsdl, magento-core, wsi

In app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsi.xml

From the tag for this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="catalogProductCreateEntity">
```

I want to delete or change type with a custom module

```
<xsd:element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0" />
```

The problem is that Magento will merge ALL the xml so if we try to remove an element it will merge the original into the XML

**Explaination:**

```
<complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
               <all>
                   <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                   <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
               </all>
   </complexType>
```

From above code now I want to remove or change type of

```
<element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
```

**If I put same element with different type then both will merge**